# PySpark - data mismatch error when trying to split a column content

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, split

I'm trying to use PySpark's `split()` method on a column that has data formatted like:

```
[6b87587f-54d4-11eb-95a7-8cdcd41d1310, 603, landing-content, landing-content-provider]
```

my intent is to extract the 4th element after the last comma.

I'm using a syntax like:

```
mydf.select("primary_component").withColumn("primary_component_01",f.split(mydf.primary_component, "\,").getItem(0)).limit(10).show(truncate=False)
```

But I'm consistently getting this error:

> "cannot resolve 'split(mydf.`primary_component`, ',')' due to data
> type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however,
> 'mydf.`primary_component`' is of
> structuuid:string,id:int,project:string,component:string
> type.;;\n'Project [primary_component#17,
> split(split(primary_component#17, ,)[1], \,)...

I've also tried escaping the "," using \, \\ or not escaping it at all and this doesn't make any difference. Also, removing the ".getItem(0)" produces no difference.

What am I doing wrong? Feeling a dumbass but I don't know how to fix this...
Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: Can you update the question with the schema of `mydf` using `mydf.printSchema`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the error:

```
"cannot resolve 'split(mydf.`primary_component`, ',')' due to data
type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however,
'mydf.`primary_component`' is of
struct<uuid:string,id:int,project:string,component:string>
```

because your column `primary_component` is using a struct type when `split` expects `string` columns.

Since `primary_component` is already a struct and you are interested in the value after your last comma you may try the following using dot notation

```py
mydf.withColumn("primary_component_01","primary_component.component")
```

In the error message, spark has shared the schema for your struct as

```
struct<uuid:string,id:int,project:string,component:string>
```

i.e.

| column | data type |
| --- | --- |
| uuid | string |
| id | int |
| project | string |
| component | string |

For future debugging purposes, you may use `mydf.printSchema()` to show the schema of the spark dataframe in use.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't aware of the struct type and the error message didn't mean anything to me. It was even easier than I thought! Now it works